# How to get status code using requests library while tesing in Django

Tags: python, django, python-requests, django-testing, django-tests

I am writing test cases for my Django application but I am using requests package in Python to access the status code, and then use the assert statement. This test case is for Staff Users only:

```
class StaffClientServerTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_login_staff(self):
        User.objects.create_superuser('abc', 'abc@gmail.com', '1234')
        self.client.login(username='abc', password='1234')
        self.client.get('/dashboard/')
        s = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/dashboard/')
        print s.status_code
        self.assertEqual(200, s.status_code)
```

Only staff users have access to the dashboard, so I created a staff user object. The following line

`self.client.login(username='abc', password='1234')` is coming to be true.
`self.client.get('/dashboard/')` if I print out this line, it shows the html content of the page which means that my staff user can access the `dashboard`.

But when I use the request module to see the status code of `dashboard` url it shows that `status code = 500`, and my test is failing.

`s = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/dashboard/')
print s.status_code`

Could anyone tell me where I am going wrong here? Why my status code is coming out be 500, even though the staff user can access the dashboard and print out its contents using `print self.client.get('/dashboard/')`. Help!

Comment: You should either specify auth credentials to `requests.get` or not use `requests.get` at all in your tests and test `self.client` because you login with `self.client` method and `requests.get` is another thing so logging in with `self.client` does not mean you will will be subsequently be authenticated to do other stuff with another library (like `requests` here). Just think carefully about what you are supposed to be testing and test just that. Also HTTP 500 is not a right status code if you are just not authenticated so you should fix your dashboard.

Comment: Any idea how to get status code? I need to test by status code.

Comment: I have disabled my admin page so thats why I am getting status code of 500.

Comment: Why do you want to test with status code when `self.client.get('/dashboard/')` only returns the contents? Either stop testing with status code or change `self.client.get('/dashboard/')` to return status code and the contents as well.

Comment: Actually `client get()` returns a response complete with status code, there's no need to be using requests here at all.

Comment: When I print out client.get() it is just giving me the content of dashboard. Could you give me an example as how to get status code from client.get()

Comment: @DanielRoseman Got it :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can test the case in other way:

protect your views with decorator:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_staff)
def dashboard(request, ...):
    # ...
```

and then request with `requests` to see if you are banned to see the page. if you are banned (403 forbidden), then your views is working correctly. To verify if your views works correctly for staff users, remove the decorator and request again, if you go thru this time, then everything is fine, the only thing to test is then the logic inside the views.

but right now, you are getting 500 instead of 403, which means you have backend errors. fix them first

Comment: I have disabled my admin page that's why I am getting 500 error. Otherwise everything is fine